# Obscure C syntax for Tomohiko Sakamoto's algorithm

Tags: c, syntax, dayofweek

I stumbled upon this version of the Sakamoto algorithm

```
dow(m,d,y){y-=m<3;return(y+y/4-y/100+y/400+"-bed=pen+mad."[m]+d)%7;}
```

I tried it on ideone.com and it actually works. I'm not interested in how the algorithm works, it's the syntax that baffles me.

I consider myself an intermediate C programmer and I have absolutely no idea what's going on in the `"-bed=pen+mad."[m]` part of the code.

What is that???

Comment: @dxiv, if it were `m["-bed=pen+mad."]`, then it would be that. But here, it's luckily in the usual order, with the array on the left, outside the brackets, and an integer as the index inside them.

Comment: @ilkkachu True that, I misread.

Answer (score 5):

That's [array subscription](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access) on a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal). Remember that a string literal is actually just a pointer to static memory.

The operation is equivalent to:

```
int m = 0;
char *str = "-bed=pen+mad.";
str[m];
```

`char` is a scalar type, and thus you can do arithmetic with the value.

Comment: I know, I feel so silly now. But seeing it all crumpled up like that crashed my brain! I'm used to write simpler, more readable code

Comment: Keep in mind this is a bit of a cheeky hack that makes use of ASCII character values. It's inherently convoluted!

Comment: I also suspect that many modern compilers would frown upon that

Comment: Subscripting a string literal is perfectly fine in modern compilers. The original Sakamoto method is written in K&R C however, which is horribly outdated (no function return/argument types, they default to `int`) and will raise warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it. The algorithm needs a lookup table for the value to add, based on the month.

`"-bed=pen+mad."` is a **string**, which is an array of `char`

Its values are

```
0: ASCII '-' not relevant since the month 0 does not exist
1: ASCII 'b' = 98
2: ASCII 'e' = 101
3: ASCII 'd' = 100
4: ASCII '=' = 61
5: ASCII 'p' = 122
6: ASCII 'e' = 101
7: ASCII 'n' = 110
8: ASCII '+' = 43
9: ASCII 'm' = 109
10: ASCII 'a' = 97
11: ASCII 'd' = 100
12: ASCII '.' = 46
```

The month `m` is used as index so that if we're for instance in February i.e index 2, the position 2 of the array is char 'e' and the value 101 gets added to the equation.

It gets confusing because the plus and the equal make it look like an equation and the apparent words like bed, pen and mad trick the brain into looking for a meaning that isn't there. It's just a bunch of characters.

Whoever wrote this was hardcore

Comment: The lack of whitespace is what makes it unnecessarily hard to read. `y -= m < 3; return (y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + "-bed=pen+mad."[m] + d) % 7;` would look better, though there's still the `"xyz"[i]` in there. Stuff like that deserves to be ran through a program like `indent` that fixes the indentation and spacing (or tries to). I would call it a bit obfuscated instead of hardcore. (Unless the situation is actually so dire that there's no space to spell out the lookup table in numbers.)

Answer (score 0):

```
"-bed=pen+mad."[0] is '-' or, probably, 45
"-bed=pen+mad."[1] is 'b' or, probably, 98
...
"-bed=pen+mad."[12] is '.' or, probably, 46
"-bed=pen+mad."[13] is '\0' or 0
```

As that value is eventually going to be `(...) % 7`

```
"-bed=pen+mad."[0] % 7 // probably 3
"-bed=pen+mad."[1] % 7 // probably 0
...
"-bed=pen+mad."[12] % 7 // probably 4
"-bed=pen+mad."[13] % 7 // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The expanded version of Tomohiko Sakamoto's dayofweek() is [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Sakamoto%27s_methods).

`"-bed=pen+mad."` is an array of constant chars that can also be written this way:

```
const char tab[] = { '-', 'b', 'e', 'd', '=', 'p', 'e', 'n', '+', 'm', 'a', 'd', '.', 0 };
```

Considering this is ASCII, `"-bed=pen+mad."` may also be written:

```
const char tab[] = { 45, 98, 101, 100, 61, 112, 101, 110, 43, 109, 97, 100, 46, 0 };
```

Now, considering the end result will eventually be % 7, this can also be written:

```
const char tab[] = { 3, 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4, 0 };
```

And now, we see that for any month `m` between 1 and 12, `"-bed=pen+mad."[m]` is the same (congruent % 7)  as `tab[m]` which is exactly the same as `t[m-1]` in the expanded version.